# Leetcode "Longest Consecutive Sequence" problem and Runtime Error For Test Case - [0]

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve the Leetcode Longest Consecutive Sequence problem and I run into a runtime  error for Test Case [0] in C++.
Question :
**Given an unsorted array of integers nums, return the length of the longest consecutive elements sequence. You must write an algorithm that runs in O(n) time.**
*Input: nums = [100,4,200,1,3,2]
Output: 4
Explanation: The longest consecutive elements sequence is [1, 2, 3, 4]. Therefore its length is 4.*

My solution is below:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int longestConsecutive(vector<int>& nums) {
        if(nums.size()==0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(nums.size()==1){
            return 1;
        }
        int size = nums.size();
        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
        vector<int> ans;
        int count =1 ;
        for(int j=0 ; j<(size-1) ; j++){
            if(nums[j]==nums[j+1]){
                nums.erase(nums.begin()+j);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<(size-1) ; i++){
            int s1 = nums[i]+1;
            int s2 = nums[i+1];
            if(s1==s2){
                count +=1;
            }
            else{
                ans.push_back(count);
                count =0;
            }
        }
        sort(ans.begin(),ans.end());
        int size2 = ans.size();
        int n = size2-1;
        return ans[n];
    }
};
```

I Added This Line
`if(nums.size()==1){ return 1; }`

To Automatically Return 1 while nums = [0].

Comment: Using `nums.erase(nums.begin()+j);` and iterating to`(size-1)` without updatng `size` looks dangerous.

Comment: Sorting likely pushes you out of O(n) to at least O(n log n)